# When events should be used in SFML?

Tags: c++, drawing, draw, sfml

I am confused about how to get inputs from `Mouse` or `Keyboard`. As an example, I want to draw little dots on my `Mouse` position when I pressed the button of my `Mouse`. Which implementation should I follow?

I have used `window.pollEvent` function to catch the mouse pressed event in the code below.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "Paint");
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> dots;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        if (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
            
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                sf::CircleShape shape(10);
                shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
                shape.setPosition(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y);
                dots.push_back(shape);
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        for (auto& i : dots) {
            window.draw(i);
        }

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or should I do it in the way like this?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "Paint");
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> dots;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        if (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
            sf::CircleShape shape(10);
            shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
            shape.setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition().x, sf::Mouse::getPosition().y);
            dots.push_back(shape);
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        for (auto& i : dots) {
            window.draw(i);
        }

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the latter is the appropriate one, then where the `if` block that checks if the mouse button is pressed should be located, before `window.clear()` or between `window.clear()` and `window.draw()` ?
I could not understand the different between them thoroughly. SFML documentation, for example, shows the latter implemenatation for gunfire action but I could not figure out why. Thanks...

Comment: In theory, both ways should work equally. Just do it the way that makes more sense for your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially asking about the two ways for handling user input:

- **Events**: handling objects that represent an occurrence.
- **Real-time input**: querying the input device about its real-time state.

Your first approach – calling [`sf::Window::pollEvent()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7) – relies on *events*. It is an *asynchronous* mechanism; the button may not be pressed when your code handles the event. Event handling is usually the way to go if all you are interested in is **whether the state of the input device has undergone a change**<sup>X</sup>, e.g., a button has been pressed or released.

Your second approach – calling [`sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#ab647159eb88e369a0332a9c5a7ba6687) – is based on *real-time input*. It consists of querying the mouse whether a given button is pressed at the moment of calling the function. This approach for handling user input is usually the way to go if you just want to **find out the current state of the input device**.

---

<sup>X</sup>Note, however, that events can be *repeated* (e.g., if you keep a key pressed for a long time), and therefore they may not necessarily imply a change in the state of the input device. You can disable this with [`sf::Window::SetKeyRepeatEnabled()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#aef9f2b14c10ecba8a8df95dd51c5bb73), though.